# Appending new rows based on column header using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on 2 Excel sheets which has common fields. I will need to paste data in sheet2 based on column header and below the existing data using VBA. Eg:

**table1:**

```
ID Name  Custcode CustName
1  Aryan  0020    Aryan Ent
2  SUman  0030    Suman Ent
3  Ramesh 0040    Ramesh Ent
```

**table2:**

```
ID Name  Alias Name Custcode CustName   Prodcode Proddesc
1  Aryan  Alex      0020     Aryan Ent  xx001    Books 
2  SUman  Sandy     0030     Suman Ent  xx002    online
```

**Target table:**

```
ID Name  Alias Name Custcode CustName   Prodcode Proddesc
1  Aryan  Alex      0020     Aryan Ent  xx001    Books 
2  SUman  Sandy     0030     Suman Ent  xx002    online 
3  Ramesh           0040     Ramesh Ent
```

I have found the below code on internet but I need a tweak for this. It is pasting the entire column and not appending the new rows:

```
Sub copycolumns()
    Dim i As Integer, searchedcolumn As Integer, searchheader As Object
    For i = 1 To 83
        Set searchheader = Sheets("Temp").Cells(1, i)
        searchedcolumn = 0
        On Error Resume Next
        searchedcolumn = Sheets("Malaysia Live data").Rows(1).Find(what:=searchheader.Value, lookat:=xlWhole).Column
        On Error GoTo 0
        If searchedcolumn <> 0 Then
           Sheets("Malaysia Live data").Columns(searchedcolumn).Copy Destination:=searchheader
        End If
        Next i
   End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show any coding you've tried, or any attempts you have made? If not, it will be difficult to help. I suggest that you record what you are trying to do, in a macro, see if you can work it out, and go from there.

Comment: I have found the below code on internet but i need a tweak for this. It is pasting the entire column and not appending the new rows.

Comment: Sub copycolumns()
 Dim i As Integer, searchedcolumn As Integer, searchheader As Object

 For i = 1 To 83

    Set searchheader = Sheets("Temp").Cells(1, i)
    
    

    searchedcolumn = 0
    On Error Resume Next
   searchedcolumn = Sheets("Malaysia Live data").Rows(1).Find(what:=searchheader.Value, lookat:=xlWhole).Column
   On Error GoTo 0

   If searchedcolumn <> 0 Then
      Sheets("Malaysia Live data").Columns(searchedcolumn).Copy Destination:=searchheader
   End If

 Next i

 End Sub

Answer (score 0):

A very basic program, with the locations hardcoded.

```
Sub test_1()

Dim a As Variant
Dim b As Variant

a = 2

Worksheets("Target Table").Activate

While Worksheets("Table 1").Cells(a, 1) <> vbNullString

    Cells(a, 1) = Worksheets("Table 1").Cells(a, 1)
    Cells(a, 2) = Worksheets("Table 1").Cells(a, 2)
    Cells(a, 5) = Worksheets("Table 1").Cells(a, 3)
    Cells(a, 6) = Worksheets("Table 1").Cells(a, 4)

    b = WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(a, 2), Worksheets("Table 2").Range("B:B"))

    If Not IsError(b) Then

        Cells(a, 3) = Worksheets("Table 2").Cells(b, 3)
        Cells(a, 8) = Worksheets("Table 2").Cells(b, 8)
        Cells(a, 7) = Worksheets("Table 2").Cells(b, 7)

    End If

    b = vbNullString

    a = a + 1

Wend


End Sub
```

You might look at ***HLookUp*** and additional ***Match*** functions.